# How can a file be changed in Git / Github without a commit

Tags: git, github

We have a situation where sometimes a file in github reverts to a previous version.  We only have a master branch.  We can see the change in the commit history, and it is the last change that has occurred for that file, but viewing the file in Github and pull / fetch from client tools shows an older version.

One possible symptom is that normally I see this when viewing each commit at the repository level

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Commit</td>
    <td>Parent</td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>     
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, in the case where the file has lost its changes, it looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Commit</td>
    <td>Parent</td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>1</td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>2</td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>2</td>     
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>4</td>     
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the change made in commit 3 has gone.

Comment: (Skimmed through the context) You can change the file, commit it, and squash the commits?

Comment: Is anyone pushing non-fast-forward commits? (e.g., either using + in the branch name or using --force)

Comment: Disable "force" push on your repository

Comment: In the second scenario, I take it that `master` is pointing to commit 5; what  is pointing to commit 3? Something has to be pointing to it for you to be able to see it.

Comment: Also, please double check that commit 5 really only has a single parent, as opposed to having both 4 and 3 as parents.

Comment: No, it wasn't a force push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is what I bet is happening here: either commit 5 has both 3 and 4 as parents (i.e. it is a merge commit), or some descendant of commit 5 is a merge commit, with one of its parents being commit 3. If that is the case, here is what happened: commits 1 and 2 were both on the server and in everyone's local repositories. Someone makes commit 3 and pushes to the server. Someone else (without pulling from the server) makes commits 4 and 5 (and perhaps more). If they try to push, they get a "no fast forward" error, since their repo is out of date. The error suggests that they pull, so they do just that. Now a pull is a fetch and a merge, but in this case, the merge resulted in conflicts, so it was not automatically committed. The person resolves the merge conflicts, but then before committing the merge notices that there are changes (totally unrelated to the conflicts) staged that they did not make. These are the changes from commit 3 that are about to be lost. The person undoes those changes, commits, then pushes.

The reason why you do not see this "botched merge" commit when you view a history of the file in question is that git by default does not include merge commits in a file's history if that file is not different than *both* of that commit's parents. In this case, the file is different than commit 3 (because the changes done in commit 3 were undone), but is not different from the other parent. To include this botched merge in the history, use `git log <filename> --full-history`.

The bottom line is that all users of the repository must be made aware that when committing a merge, they *must* commit all staged changes, even if they did not make those changes, as those are the changes that are supposed to be merged in from the "other" branch.

Comment: I think this was most likely the case.  I can see the file has changed if I look at the combined commit details of all files in the commit that came after the lost change, and it does include the file that had the botched merge.  Conceptually I expected the merge to force the user to merge against commit 3, and would know the file vs commit 2 hadn't changed and therefore update it to commit 3.  The user in question now remembers seeing the file staged to commit but thought it was a mistake because they hadn't touched that file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way this could happen in a git repository is through a force push. As can be seen in the second diagram commit 4 is dependant on commit 2. This is likely what happened:

```
1<-2<-3
```

Here is the original repo (note that git commits only point to their parent and not their children). Then someone makes commits 4 and 5, however, they have an old version of the repo and they just have commits 1 and 2. Then when they force push to the remote repo you end up with:

```
1<-2<-3
    \-4<-5
```

Commit 3 still exists in the reflog but there is no branch pointing to it. It is possible to *fix* this by disabling force push but the real issue is a team issue where git is not being used correctly.

You say that you only have one branch (master), this is an indicator of an incorrect workflow. Have a look into [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) and discuss with your members the dangers of force push. Also the model that github uses is distributed, where each member has their own repository, and other members do not have write access. In this model code is shared through pull requests. This would also be something that could help.

Good luck!

Comment: One thing to note is if this is what happened, then when someone who does have commit 3 in their local repo does a pull, they will merge commits 3 and 5, then push that merge for others to receive. So the changes in commit 3 would not really be lost.